# How to create a pointcut expression for all annotations composed of a specified annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I want to execute some code for all methods annotated with `@TestAnnotation` or other annotations that are composed of it. I thought that using `@Around("@annotation(TestAnnotation)")` should do the trick however it only works for the exact match, but not for composed annotations like `@ComposedTestAnnotation`. Is this possible to make it work? I cannot find any examples of the described scenario.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface TestAnnotation {
}
```

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@TestAnnotation
public @interface ComposedTestAnnotation {
}
```

```
@Aspect
@Service
@Slf4j
public class AspectService {

    @Around("@annotation(TestAnnotation)")
    public Object aroundTestAnnotation(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        log.info("aroundTestAnnotation executed");
        return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
    }

}
```

Comment: Do go through : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48543096/4214241

Comment: Or if you are willing to switch from Spring AOP to AspectJ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42607016/1082681